# Indexing the wrong character for an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

My program seems to be indexing the wrong character or not at all.

I wrote a basic calculator that allows expressions to be used. It works by having the user enter the expression, then turning it into a list, and indexing the first number at position 0 and then using try/except statements to index number2 and the operator. All this is in a while loop that is finished when the user enters done at the prompt.

The program seems to work fine if I type the expression like this "1+1" but if I add spaces "1 + 1" it cannot index it or it ends up indexing the operator if I do "1+1" followed by "1 + 1".

I have asked in a group chat before and someone told me to use tokenization instead of my method, but I want to understand why my program is not running properly before moving on to something else.

Here is my code:
https://hastebin.com/umabukotab.py

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As a new user you should read [ask]. This site has rules about how a question should be asked, and this one does not observe them... Specifically you are supposed to provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**. I will not answer because of that, but still give you a hint: You are searching the second number in the range [1-4[, which is fine if no space character is involved, but is too short if 2 spaces are present. Good luck and hope your next question will be nicer :-)

Comment: Please put the code in your question rather than hosting it on another website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are basically lists of characters. `1+1` contains three characters, whereas `1 + 1` contains five, because of the two added spaces. Thus, when you access the third character in this longer string, you're actually accessing the middle element.

Parsing input is often *not easy*, and certainly parsing arithmetic expressions can get tricky quite quickly. Removing spaces from the input, as suggested by @Sethroph is a viable solution, but will only go that far. If you all of a sudden need to support stuff like `1+2+3`, it will still break.

Another solution would be to split your input on the operator. For example:

```py
input = '1 + 2'
terms = input.split('+')  # ['1 ', ' 2'] note the spaces
terms = map(int, terms)  # [1, 2]  since int() can handle leading/trailing whitespace
output = terms[0] + terms[1]
```

Still, although this can handle situations like `1 + 2 + 3`, it will still break when there's multiple different operators involved, or there are parentheses (but that might be something you need not worry about, depending on how complex you want your calculator to be).

IMO, a better approach would indeed be to use tokenization. Personally, I'd use parser combinators, but that may be a bit overkill. For reference, here's an [example calculator](https://parsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/lexing.html#calculator) whose input is parsed using `parsy`, a parser combinator library for Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the spaces before processing the string by using `replace()`.

Try adding in:

```py
clean_input = hold_input.replace(" ", "")
```

just after you create `hold_input`.